# InvalidOperationException (Generated value is not between 0 and 1.) Accord.net

Tags: accord.net

I'm at the moment trying to use the KMeans algorithm from the Accord.NET framework.

Heres my code:

```
private Bitmap runKMeans(Bitmap image)
    {
        // Retrieve the number of clusters
        int k = 5;

        // Create converters
        ImageToArray imageToArray = new ImageToArray(min: -1, max: +1);
        ArrayToImage arrayToImage = new ArrayToImage(image.Width, image.Height, min: -1, max: +1);

        // Transform the image into an array of pixel values
        double[][] pixels; 
        imageToArray.Convert(image, out pixels);


        // Create a K-Means algorithm using given k and a
        //  square Euclidean distance as distance metric.
        KMeans kmeans = new KMeans(k, Distance.SquareEuclidean);

        // Compute the K-Means algorithm until the difference in
        //  cluster centroids between two iterations is below 0.05
        int[] idx = kmeans.Compute(pixels, 0.05);

        // Replace every pixel with its corresponding centroid
        pixels.ApplyInPlace((x, i) => kmeans.Clusters.Centroids[idx[i]]);

        //Create a Bitmap and return it
        Bitmap result; arrayToImage.Convert(pixels, out result);

        return result;
    }
```

When I run the programm there is a exception thrown at this line:

```
int[] idx = kmeans.Compute(pixels, 0.05);
```

> Type: "System.InvalidOperationException" Generated value is not between 0 and 1.

after some research I found out that a random number generator of the KMeans algorithm is throwing this exception. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi Sascha, this is Cesar from the Accord.NET Framework. Please, can I ask if you can open a bug report in the project issue tracker and offer a sample image that is causing the problem? Thanks! https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues